# Debugging in C++

Tags: c++, debugging

I came across this code snippet. Can you explain how to use this debugging in the program.

```
#ifdef TESTING 
#define DEBUG fprintf(stderr, "====TESTING====\n") 
#define VALUE(x) cerr << "The value of " << #x << " is " << x << endl 
#define debug(...) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__) 
#else 
#define DEBUG 
#define VALUE(x) 
#define debug(...) 
#endif
```

Comment: how to use this for debugging? You trash it and use a debugger ;) Debugging is not worth littering all your code with macros when there are better ways

Comment: seriuosly, what is not clear? Did you try to call the macros to see what happens?

Comment: If you define `-DDEBUG` during compilation, or excpicitly define `DEBUG` or `TESTING` before that snippet, the compiler will use the corresponding macro in your code. If you define DEBUG, then you'll get some more debug reports in your code (That cerr statement in your snippet for example).

Comment: is more _tracing_ than (direct) _debugging_

Comment: My favorite part of this is that it assumes `using namespace std;` (or at least `using std::cerr; using std::endl;`) is present. Either this header imposes those or `using namespace std;` is expected everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather use a proper debugger than these macros, but if you really need to use those, here's how you do it:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; // better remove this and change the macro with cerr and endl instead
#define TESTING

#ifdef TESTING 
#define DEBUG fprintf(stderr, "====TESTING====\n") 
#define VALUE(x) cerr << "The value of " << #x << " is " << x << endl 
#define debug(...) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__) 
#else 
#define DEBUG 
#define VALUE(x) 
#define debug(...) 
#endif 

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a = 100;
    DEBUG; // prints "====TESTING===="
    VALUE(a); // prints "The value of a is 100"
    debug("%d + %d = %d", 1, 2, 1 + 2); // prints "1 + 2 = 3"
    return 0;
}
```

This will give you the following output:

```
====TESTING====
The value of a is 100
1 + 2 = 3
```

If you remove `#define TESTING`, you don't get any of that output, so you can remove/set it depending on whether you are "testing" or not.

Alternatively, it usually is possible to supply such defines using the build system/IDE where it could be automatically set/reset depending on the context. For instance in Visual Studio:

[image]

Comment: Great suggestion, I added an example of that.